# Is the following "connectedness" argument correct?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

**Is the following argument correct? If not, how can it be fixed?**

---

**Problem:** Prove that $X$ is connected, where $X = \{z: |z| \leq 1\} \cup \{z: |z - 2| < 1\}.$

**Argument:**

The equation $|z| \leq 1$ defines a unit disk centered at the origin while the equation $|z-2| < 1$ defines a unit disk (not containing its boundary) centered at $(2, 0).$

Suppose $U,V$ are two open sets that connect $X.$ Then 
\begin{equation}
U \cap X \neq \varnothing, V \cap X \neq \varnothing, \ \mathrm{and} \ X \subseteq U \cup V \implies \ U \cap V \neq \varnothing.
\end{equation}

Taking $X$ as in the problem, $U = \{z: |z| \leq 1\},$ and $V = \{z: |z - 2| < 1\},$ we see that $U \cap X \neq \varnothing, V \cap X \neq \varnothing, \ \mathrm{and} \ X = U \cup V.$ Thus $U \cap V \neq \varnothing,$ with the only point in common between $U$ and $V$ being $(1,0).$ So $X$ is connected.

Comment: your $U$ is not open

Comment: @user48481MirkoSwirko Sometimes, the shortest answers are the most difficult to digest...

Comment: first your $U$ as you defined it is not open. Second, you are not to pick $U,V$ yourself, but show that no matter how one picks them they would intersect each other as long as both intersect $X$ and their union covers $X$. Third, the way you picked $U,V$ they do not intersect. Read the definition and more examples and start all over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is even path-connected, hence connected. Take any two points $A,B$ in $X$. If they belong to the same circle connect them with the straight line segment between them. If they belong to different circles, connect each with a straight line segment to the point $P$ where the two circles touch $P(1,0)$.

Comment: I cannot use path-connectedness, because technically we haven't covered it yet.

Comment: I suspected that, but it does simplify the problem. And the definition of connectedness could be used along these lines. If each of $U,V$ intersects $X$ you may pick $A\in U$, $B\in V$, and then use the path that connects $A,B$ as described above, and mimic the proof that any closed line segment is connected (using the definition) ... or the proof that the real line is connected, one of these proofs ought to be done in your book.